# Correct way of doing transactional queries

Tags: php, transactions

I am trying to do multiple queries in one call, so I organized my code as below:

```
try{
    $query = $this->conn->begin_transaction();
    
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(xx, xxx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxx) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $query->bind_param("sssssssssss", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7, $var8,  $var8,  $var9, $var10);                                 
    $result1 = $query->execute();
    
    $var1= $xxx- $xxxx;
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE table2 set xxx = ? WHERE xxxx = ?");
    $query->bind_param("ss", $var1, $var2);  
    $result2 = $query->execute(); 
     
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table3 (xx, xxx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxxxx) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    $query->bind_param("ssssss", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6);    
    $result3 = $query->execute(); 
    
    $query = $this->conn->commit();

    if($result1 == true AND $result2 == true AND $result3 == TRUE){
        return "Success";
    }
    exit();   
}catch (Exception $e){
    $this->conn->rollback(); 
    throw $e;   
}
```

Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but I don't want to insert/update records in the database if all queries are not true. It would help me a lot if someone can go through the code and tell me his thoughts, this works fine but I am not sure if this is a good approach.

Comment: This seems correct to me, in theory.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Obfuscated code and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).